# How to Convert between dB Voltage and Power

Tags: rf, theory

We [read](http://www.electronicproducts.com/dBuV_and_dBm_Conversion_Calculator.aspx) that the formula for expressing microvolts in decibels is different from that for milliwatts by a factor of 2:

\$U = 20\log_{10}{\frac{u}{u_0}}\$

\$P = 10\log_{10}{\frac{p}{p_0}}\$

(Note the leading factor of 20 versus 10.)

Why is this the case? Why do we not use the factor 10 everywhere?

Comment: We use "20" because P = (V^2)/R for a constant R, hence log(a^2) = 2log(a)

Comment: \$P = VI = \frac{V^2}{Z}\$ where \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$

Comment: $$P = 10\log_{10}{\frac{p}{p_0}}= 10\log_{10}{\frac{\frac{V^2}{R}}{\frac{V_0^2}{R}}}=10\log_{10}{(\frac{V}{V_0})^2} = 20\log_{10}{\frac{V}{V_0}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about power quantities, we use the following formula:

\$ 10\log_{10}(P/P_0)dB \$

Which defines the decibel ratio in terms of power units.

However, when we deal with voltages, we actually compare the ratio of the *squares* of the voltages (because power is proportional to voltage squared, and it is useful for both decibel formulations to give the same results) which gives us:

\$10\log_{10}(V^{2}/V_0^{2})dB =  10\log_{10}[(V/V_0)^{2}] \$

According to the [list of logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities), \$\log(a^{x}) = x\log(a) \$, so we get \$2*10\log_{10}(V/V_0) = 20\log_{10}(V/V_0) \$

Comment: Thank you! I had not seen before anyone explicitly call out that it is the ratio of the *squares* being compared.

Comment: The algebra seen in G36's comment more explicitly explains why we use the squares of voltages and the normal power values.  Doing it that way ensures the decibel value of a system's output remains the same, regardless of whether you measure voltage or power.